# Wrong path font not working

Tags: html, css

I've use the font face but it seems that I'm missing something on the declaration. How should i declare to make my font work? I have that font on my working folder.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'HThin';
src: url("/assets/fontsfontsHelveticaNeue-Thin.otf") format("opentype");}

.header-text{ 
 font-family:'HThin';
 color: white;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; }
```

Comment: src: url("/assets/fonts/fontsHelveticaNeue-Thin.otf") format("opentype");}

typo error sorry

Comment: ("./assets/fonts/fontsHelveticaNeue-Thin.otf")

Comment: Does it return 404 when you request that font in Chrome Dev Tools or whatever you use? Or what it does?

Comment: Can you access it in the browser with an absolute url? For example,  `http://localhost:8080/myapp/assets/fontsfontsHelveticaNeue-Thin.otf`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path to the font is correct?
If the directory where the font is it's in the same position of the .css file you should write "../assets/fontsfontsHelveticaNeue-Thin.otf".
Btw remember vendor prefixes for @font-face http://shouldiprefix.com/#font-face

Comment: src: url("/assets/fonts/fontsHelveticaNeue-Thin.otf") format("opentype");} typo error sorry

Comment: src: url("../assets/fonts/fontsHelveticaNeue-Thin.otf") format("opentype");
still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a WebKit font generator and use the set of webkit fonts to use on a webpage.

One easy way to do is using :
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator